# How to use a CTE to insert multiple records based on hierarchy

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Lets say I have a `Customer` table that contains `CustomerId` as a primary key and `ParentCustomerId` as a foreign key and I want to cascade an insert statement to create a record for each of the Customers in the hierarchy chain.

I also have a CustomerContact table that has a clustered primary key of `CustomerId`, `PersonId`, and `DateCreated`

So if I have the following:

Customer1: `CustomerId: 1` : `ParentCustomerId: Null`

Customer2: `CustomerId: 2` : `ParentCustomerId: 1`

Customer3: `CustomerId: 3` : `ParentCustomerId: 2`

And I pass `1` into my customer ID, but I want to create 3 (although in this case the 3 is a variable, the hierarchies could go deeper) so that I insert into a different table a row for each customer in the chain.

```
declare @1 as int      --customerId
declare @2 as int      --personId for the contact
declare @3 as datetime --DateCreated 

set @1 = 1
set @2 = 1 --personId
set @3 = GetDate()

--I don't know how to use a CTE to get all the CustomerIds that are 
--
--something like 
--with cte_customers
--as
--(select CustomerId from customer
--  where ParentCustomerId = @1
--)

insert into CustomerContact
Values(@1, @2, @3)
```

How can I write a CTE to get the children of all the customers related to param `@1` and create a record in `CustomerContact` for each?

Comment: You need to use `recursive cte`

Comment: what is `set @1 = 1` ?  some language extension? a scalar constant?

Comment: @wildplasser in the final query, @1 will be a parameter, I was setting it to 1 to make a sensible example (or at least attempting to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `recursive common table expression` using `union all`.  Here's a reduced example:

```
with cte as (
    select customerid, parentcustomerid
    from customer 
    where customerid = 1
    union all 
    select c.customerid, cte.customerid
    from customer c join cte on cte.customerid = c.parentcustomerid)

 insert into customercontact
 select customerId, @1, @2 from cte
```

With your sample data, this will return 3 records and can also handle deeper relationships.

Comment: so if i changed that to `select customerid from cte`, how do i write my insert statement to create a record for each of the customerIds that are returned ?

Comment: @USER_8675309 -- not 100% sure I'm following, but are you referring to something like this: `insert into CustomerContact select customerid, @2, @3 from cte`?

Comment: "for each customerId in cte 
    insert into customercontact (customerid, @2, @3)
 next" is what I am going for.   forgive the VB.Net like syntax

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you can use my above statement.  The general syntax is `insert into ... select ...`  That will insert all the records from the `cte` table.  Within the `select` statement, you can then include your other parameters.

Comment: sorry, killed it -- i found my answer